# Datastore API and Chooser Drop-in of Dropbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api, datastore

I am developing an iOS application and I want to use a datastore in the cloud, and I want download my files of Dropbox too. Recently, I discover the datastore API of Dropbox for save my database in the cloud. Is there anyway to combine in the same iOS application the Chooser Drop-in of Dropbox and its new datastore API?? Can be any problem or incompatibility using two app-keys in the same iOS application??

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just do this. Just use the same app key for both. (See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/54/use-drop-ins-with-any-app-key.)

Comment: Thank you! It's just I need! =D